# Facebook Graph API error - Unknown path components

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My function to list add_group_account id of a particular user ends up by receiving the following error.

```
Message: Unknown path components: /adaccountgroups
```

I'm following this guideline [Facebook API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account-group/v13.0)

```
public function tp()
{ 
    
    $fb = new Facebook([ 
      'app_id' => "621201298943758",
      'app_secret' => "f0aa4ae743ef.................",
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5', 
      'default_access_token' => "EAAI0ZBrLB7w4BAIUyoGjSB50ZBsXbPxYfCjk6WxPQIa.................................",
     ]);
     
    
    try {
          // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
          $response = $fb->get(
            '/me/adaccountgroups',
            'EAAI0ZBrLB7w4BAIUyoGjSB50ZBs.....................'
          );
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
          echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
          echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        }
        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
     
}
```

Comment: Try `/{ad user ID}/adaccountgroups` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have discovered there is no endpoint or function by the name "adaccountgroups"available even though it was mentioned in their own documentation.

To get the add account ID corresponding to a particular user account it has to be called in following pattern

curl

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/me/adaccounts?access_token=EAAI0ZBrLB7w...............
```

SDK

```
$response = $fb->get(
            '/me/adaccounts',
            '{token.....}'
          );
```